# Functions with identical names in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to compile old project, but I got an error. That project implements function `dprintf`, which is some kind of a `printf` function. However when I tried to compile that project today I found out that `dprintf` is already defined in `stdio.h`. So my question is - how to hide the standard `dprintf` function, because now I'm constantly getting an error like this:

```
ntreg.c:82: error: conflicting types for 'dprintf'
/usr/include/stdio.h:397: note: previous declaration of 'dprintf' was here
ntreg.c:93: error: conflicting types for 'dprintf'
/usr/include/stdio.h:397: note: previous declaration of 'dprintf' was here
```

Comment: Why don't you simply change the function name?

Comment: Are you trying to implement `dprintf` yourself (i.e. your own part-implementation of `stdio.h`) - or just create some extra function that could well be called `foobar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rename your implementation to something else like

```
int dprintf(... parameters ...)
```

to

```
int not_stdio_dprintf(... parameters ...)
```

and then wherever you use it add

```
#define dprintf not_stdio_dprintf
```

Answer (score 6):

`dprintf()` is not defined by the Standard.

If you configure your compiler for Standard C, the function should no longer be exposed

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic ...
```

Comment: Of course, that's also an excelent Idea, and I bet there is also a macro that could disable it.